# Server Not Found

Tags: internet

I'm getting this classic error very frequently. some sites open like charm but majority throw up this classic error and on multiple refreshes i'm able to access them.

i'm using mozilla firefox on Ubuntu Mate 16.04

**update:** 
i tried `ping www.google.com` it returned

**update:**
[image]

> unknown host www.google.com

**update** : 
Updated firefox to 50.0.2 (latest version). Shall let you know if it works.

Comment: Can you tell the version of firefox you are using? 50.0.2 is the most latest version. And there could be some problem in the connectivity of the Internet. I agree that you can access some websites and some of them not. Instead of refreshing the same web page, stop loading that web page, and try refreshing the one you have already opened or open the one which you are sure that will always open.

Comment: @learner 47.0  i clicked three links 1 opened and 2 failed. i refreshed the link that opened and it worked again

Comment: Then try updating firefox. Is it fresh install of OS? Are you sure you haven't messed up with your network for any other experiment?

Comment: @learner my version of firefox came bundled with ubuntu mate i'm using

Comment: @learner haven't done anything except for adding dns 8.8.8.8 , 8.8.4.4 . Ataching screenshot.

Comment: @learner updated my firefox to 50.0.2

Comment: So is it working now? More than the version of Firefox, I think the problem is with that DNS. Try recreating new connection.